# SFCC API to remove a product from the product set

Tags: api, product, commerce-cloud

Are there any SFCC API to remove a product from the product set?

It is a very easy thing to do from BM: just go to the **Product Sets** tab, select a product set from which to remove, go to **Products** tab, remove the product. But I can not find any API for that.

The only two options I have is to generate an .xml file and run its import at runtime so that to change the product set or use OCAPI. I would like to achieve the same with the API. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an Script API for this? Products are read-only in storefront context for a good reason - you have multiple users accessing them in a concurrent manner.
What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

UPDATE:

Just construct an xml following the pattern below with the list of products you want to remain in the product set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" catalog-id="apparel-catalog">

    <product product-id="fall-look">
        <product-set-products>
            <product-set-product product-id="013742003314"/>
            <product-set-product product-id="25592648"/>
            <product-set-product product-id="25698039"/>
        </product-set-products>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

After that use the standard catalog import job step component https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/jobstepapi/html/api/jobstep.ImportCatalog.html

Comment: I am creating a job which would create specific product sets and remove others. I need this so that the client would not have to create the product sets manually, but uploaded a file specifying the product sets. The file which specifies the product sets is going to be created manually.

Comment: And why not manipulate the file to generate a standard catalog.xml where you can both create and remove objects using the "mode" attribute of the product element? See https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/xsd/catalog.xsd

Comment: I have updated the answer above (I figured you want to add/remove products in the product set, not the actual product set), hope this helps.